# How to properly configure MAIL_URL?

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

The follwoing smtp url giving me an error

```
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://mail_name@outlook.com:Password@smtp.outlook.com:457";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to url-encode your user name and password.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, your issue is that your user name (and perhaps your password) contain a character that cannot be placed in a URL as-is, and therefore needs to be encoded.

I want to take this opportunity to provide a little more in-depth answer to the issue of configuring the `MAIL_URL` environment variable.

If you simply need a quick string that will work, do:

```
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://"+encodeURIComponent("mail_name@outlook.com")+":"+encodeURIComponent("Password")+"@smtp.outlook.com:457";
```

Also take into account that you may need to use `smtps` for secure connection, and if it uses TLS, your connection may fail.

I recommend to read the rest if you need anything more robust.

## URL

A URL has the following structure:

```sh
scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]
```

The scheme would be either `smtp` or `smtps` (for secure connection), and in this scenario you will also set the user, password, host and (most likely) port.

Each of the parts needs to be encoded in a way that is suitable for use in a URL, but since hosts (domains) are normally already appropriate, you only need to make sure that your user name/password are encoded.

In EcmaScript, [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) can be used for this.

## MAIL_URL and node environment variables

Meteor checks the value of `process.env.MAIL_URL` when sending an email.

[`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) is populated by node.js with the environment variables available to it on startup.

It is possible to add properties to it on runtime, so setting `process.env.MAIL_URL` before sending an email will work. However, you should do so wisely to prevent your secrets from leaking.

I would suggest 2 methods for setting it up, either using `settings.json` or using the environment variable itself.

### using settings.json

Create a `json` file in your project. It is highly recommended not to commit it into source control with the rest of your code.

for example: **config/development/settings.json**

```
{
  "smtp": {
    "isSecure": true,
    "userName": "your_username",
    "password": "your_password",
    "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "port": 465
  }
}
```

And somewhere in your server code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Meteor.settings && Meteor.settings.smtp) {
    const { userName, password, host, port, isSecure } = Meteor.settings.smtp;
    const scheme = isSecure ? 'smtps' : 'smtp';
    process.env.MAIL_URL = `${scheme}://${encodeURIComponent(userName)}:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@${host}:${port}`;
  }
});
```

Then you can run Meteor with the `--settings` switch.

```
meteor run --settings config/development/settings.json
```

### using an environment variable

You can set the environment variable to the encoded string. If you want a utility script (for zsh on *nix) that will convert it (depends on `node`):

**mail_url.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

alias urlencode='node -e "console.log(encodeURIComponent(process.argv[1]))"'

ENC_USER=`urlencode $2`
ENC_PASS=`urlencode $3`

MAIL_URL="$1://$ENC_USER:$ENC_PASS@$4"

echo $MAIL_URL
```

which can be used as follows:

```sh
$ chmod +x mail_url.sh
$ MAIL_SCHEME=smtps
$ MAIL_USER=foo@bar.baz
$ MAIL_PASSWORD=p@$$w0rd
$ MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com:465
$ export MAIL_URL=$(./mail_url.sh $MAIL_SCHEME $MAIL_USER $MAIL_PASSWORD $MAIL_HOST)
$ echo $MAIL_URL
smtps://foo%40bar.baz:p%4015766w0rd@smtp.gmail.com:465
```